# Match a string from File1 in File2 and replace the string in File1 with corresponding matched string in File2

Tags: perl, awk

The title may be confusing, here's what I'm trying to do:

> ```
> File1 
> 12=921:5,895:5,813:5,853:5,978:5,807:5,1200:5,1067:5,827:5
>
> File2 
> Tom 12 John 921 Mike 813
>
> Output 
> Tom=John:5,Mike:5
> ```

The file2 has the values of the numbers in file1, and I want match and replace the numbers with string values. I tried this with my limited knowledge in awk, but couldn't do it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @kikumbob I tried splitting the line in file1 using the ':' and '=' delimeter, and match in file 2, but not able to replace it with the corresponding column.

Comment: You want to split on the `,` and not the `:`. Then, you can loop though the data set one group at a time. As you loop through each set, you can try a substitution. If the substitution works, display the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[ =:,]"
}

FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$0
    next
}

$2 in a {
    split(a[$2],b)
    for (i=3;i<=NF-1;i+=2) {
        for (j=2;j<=length(b)-1;j+=2) {
            if ($(i+1) == b[j]) {
                line = (line ? line "," : "") $i ":" b[j+1]
            }
        }
    }
    print $1 "=" line
    line = ""
}
```

Results:

```
Tom=John:5,Mike:5
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "[ =:,]" 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$0; next } $2 in a { split(a[$2],b); for (i=3;i<=NF-1;i+=2) for (j=2;j<=length(b)-1;j+=2) if ($(i+1) == b[j]) line = (line ? line "," : "") $i ":" b[j+1]; print $1 "=" line; line = "" }' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

> Change awk's field separator to a either a space, equals, colon or comma.
>
> 'FNR==NR { ... }' is only true for the first file in the arguments list.
>
> So when processing file1, awk will add column '1' to an array and we assign the whole line as a value to this array element.
>
> 'next' will simply skip processing the rest of the script, and read the next line of input.
>
> When awk has finished reading the input in file1, it will continue reading file2. However, this also resets 'FNR' to '1', so awk will skip processing the 'FNR==NR' block for file2 because it is not longer true.
>
> So for file2: if column '2' can be found in the array mentioned above:
>
> > Split the value of the array element into another array. This essentially splits up the whole line in file1.
> >
> > Now create two loops.
> >
> > > The first will loop through all the names in file2
> > >
> > > And the second will loop through all the values in the (second) array (this essentially loops over all the fields in file1).
> >
> > Now when a value succeeding a name in file2 is equal to one of the key numbers in file1, create a line construct that looks like: 'name:number_following_key_number_from_file1'.
> >
> > When more names and values are found during the loops, the quaternary construct '( ... ? ... : ...)' adds these elements onto the end of the line. It's like an if statement; if there's already a line, add a comma onto the end of it, else don't do anything.
> >
> > When all the loops are complete, print out column '1' and the line. Then empty the line variable so that it can be used again.

HTH. Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks so much, Steve. It would be great if you could explain me the code.

Comment: @Kaartz: No problem. I've added a bit of an explanation. If there's a concept that I haven't covered please let me know and I can try and explain it some more. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The following may work as a template:

```
skrynesaver@busybox ~/ perl -e '$values="12=921:5,895:5,813:5,853:5,978:5,807:5,1200:5,1067:5,827:5";
$data = "Tom 12 John 921 Mike 813";
($line,$values)=split/=/,$values;
@values=split/,/,$values;
$values{$line}="=";
map{$_=~/(\d+)(:\d+)/;$values{$1}="$2";}@values;
if ($data=~/\w+\s$line\s/){
  $data=~s/(\w+)\s(\d+)\s?/$1$values{$2}/g;
}
print "$data\n";
'
Tom=John:5Mike:5
skrynesaver@busybox ~/
```